# How to load a ClearCase snapshot view preserving timestamps

Tags: clearcase

I'm trying to create a new snapshot view (from the command line) and load the vob, preserving timestamps.  After the view has been created, I edit the config spec as needed, followed by the line:

```
load /vob/myvob
```

On save, it prompts me:

```
Set config spec and load snapshot view "myviewname"? [yes]
```

Upon typing "yes", the vob gets loaded with the *current* timestamp.  Since I prefer it to be loaded with the timestamps preserved, my workaround is to delete the contents of the vob, and then from the command line call:

```
cleartool update -rename -ptime -force
```

where the "ptime" flag tells it to preserve the timestamp of the file.

Is there a simpler way to do this with the "load" command within the config spec?

**EDIT:** I'm using ClearCase 7.1.2.4 on Solaris 8

Comment: I have edited the answer to reference the ClearCase 7.1 version: same option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the '-ptime' option to 'cleartool mkview'.  See:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm

Comment: Hot dog, that did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Clearteam Explorer preferences](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_prefs_ccexplorer_details.htm):

**Preserve version creation time when files are updated or loaded from the server**

> By default, the last modified time of a ClearCase element is the time when the element was last loaded, updated, or restored.
>   **To specify the modified time of the element as the last modified time of that version in the VOB, click the Preserve version creation time when files are updated or loaded from the server preference**.
>
> Note that this preference setting can also affect an Undo Checkout or Undo Hijack operation.
>   Undoing a hijack operation reloads the corresponding version from the server and restores the last modified time as specified by this preference setting.
>   Likewise, undoing a checkout operation restores the corresponding version of the element and also restores the last modified time according to this preference setting.

Note: you have the [same option for ClearCase 7.1.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_prefs_explorer.htm).

> From the main menu bar, click `Window > Preferences` to open the `Preferences` dialog box.
>
> - If you are using the Rational ClearCase Remote Client for Eclipse, select `Team > ClearCase Remote Client > ClearCase Explorer`,
> - If you are using the Rational ClearCase Remote Client, select `ClearCase Remote Client > ClearCase Explorer`.
>
> To specify the modified time of the element as the last modified time of that version in the VOB (instead of the time when the element was last loaded, updated, or restored), click the `Preserve version creation time when files are updated or loaded from the server` preference

Comment: Hmm... I'm not seeing that.  Not even a Window menu to click.  I'm using the command `/usr/atria/bin/xclearcase` to bring up the ClearCase File Browser, which I'm guessing is different from ClearCase Explorer.  I'm not sure how to launch that.

Comment: @splungebob yes, I don't see a -ptime option in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/xclearcase.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-72

Answer (score 0):

On command line firstly, create empty view with the following command:

```
cleartool mkview -snapshot -tag <tag_name> -vws \\<computer_name>\<views_folder>\<view_name> <path_of_localstorage>
```

Then load it based on the config spec with the following command:

```
cleartool setcs -force -overwrite -ptime <CS_Folder_Path>\<CS_File_Name>
```

For details you may follow [this link](https://iffetoguz.com/2016/10/04/creating-snapshot-view-via-clearcase-cleartool-commands/).